# Population growth projection

Tags: self-study, population, demography

[image]Que ) ***Population grows in such a manner that [1/P(t) ]* dP(t)/dt is a linear function of log P(t) where P(t) is the population size at time t . Obtain the explicit expression for P(t)***

In this question , We have to find the expression for the population function P(t)

**My contribution**

I have studied  force of mortality

Force of mortality at age x is defined as the ratio of instantaneous rate of decrease in value of l at age x ( number of persons living at any specified age x)  it is denoted by
μ  = - d( log l(at x )/dx .

It gives nominal annual rate of mortality

Now if we observe the question in same way can we say that the expression in question means opposite of mortality .

Please confirm the answer

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** You might be interested in using the log-differentiation rule:

$$\frac{d}{dt} \log P(t) = \frac{1}{P(t)} \frac{dP}{dt} (t).$$

Try setting this as a linear function of $\log P (t)$ and see where that gets you.

Comment: i have tried solving using your hint , please have a look at what I have done .

Comment: Hey could you tell if this is correct,  and also is this the complete answer because the question is asking explicit expression for P (t) .

Comment: Sorry, not correct and not complete.

Comment: Your help would be highly appreciated sir .

Comment: For self-study/questions like this, we limit our help to hints.